# what does "crashlytics app initializer Disabling" mean?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I use FirebaseCrashlytics 6.0.0 and it doesn't work.

In Android Studio logcat I see the following error and I would like to know what this means:

> crashlytics app initializer Disabling

[image: Error message]

Comment: Fabric/Firebaser here - taking a look at the errors you're seeing, they don't look like any error messages that Crashlytics provisions. Looks like this issue is happening in the Debug.bindings.h file - could we see that file/get any more info about what's going on at that line?